# Indexing and robust commands

Tags: indexing, robust-commands

I need to do a little massaging of my index entries before putting them into the index, so I defined a helper command.  For the MWE, I'll just let the helper pass straight to `\index`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeindex
\newcommand\indexhelper[1]{\index{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\RobustIndexHelper[1]{\index{#1}}
\begin{document}
A
\index{$\vec a$}
\indexhelper{$\vec a$}
\RobustIndexHelper{$\vec a$}
\end{document}
```

(The `A` is there so that there's some output, or else the `.idx` file is blank.)  The resulting `.idx` file is

```
\indexentry{$\vec a$}{1}
\indexentry{$\mathaccentV {vec}17Ea$}{1}
\indexentry{$\mathaccentV {vec}17Ea$}{1}
```

I assume that this is something to do with fragility, which is why I tried the `\DeclareRobustCommand`; but that's basically cargo culting and, even worse, it didn't work.  Aside from "don't put such entries into your bibliography" and "don't use a helper command", how can I deal with this?

Comment: Note that, also with Christian’s solution, `\bar{d}` would be sorted before `\vec{a}`. So the best thing would be to help the indexing with the `@` feature, which would make irrelevant the issue you're facing.

Comment: @egreg, I agree (and that's part of what the actual helper does), but I'm not sure how that makes the issue irrelevant.  No matter how it's sorted, I still need to get commands like `\vec` unmolested into the index file, and `\indexhelper{a@$\vec a$}` (without ChristianHupfer's `\detokenize` suggestion) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write the literal string of the input for the wrapper command, i.e. such that possible fragile content for the wrapper, (and `\vec` is not robust).

The easiest way is `\detokenize` (an e-TeX - addition) (but I am not sure whether there might be some catcode issues )

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeindex
\newcommand\indexhelper[1]{\index{\detokenize{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\RobustIndexHelper[1]{\index{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}

A
\index{$\vec a$}
\indexhelper{$\vec a$}
\indexhelper{$\vec b$}
\RobustIndexHelper{$\vec c$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I take it that `\RobustIndexHelper` is there just to parallel my document?  Just `\indexhelper` by itself seems to work fine, but maybe there's something important I'm missing.

Comment: @LSpice: both helper commands do the same right now. It depends what you really have in mind. If you are thinking about writing commands to a file, the robust command version is the better way

Comment: I'm not interested in writing to a file for its own sake, but, of course, indexing does use an `.idx` file.  My helper is basically just `\newcommand\indexhelper[1]{\index{#1}#1}`, that is, indexing the term and dropping it in the document at the same time (which, it seems from other questions here, is a common task).  For those purposes, is the robust version better?

Comment: @LSpice: No.... and filler text :D

Comment: The only objection might be if you would use `imakeidx` package -- in this case you can do more than one index (i.e. you can have a person name index and a 'science term' index) separately. In this case, `\index` has an optional argument. You would lose that possibility with your wrapper (as being defined in that way)